# Identity Server 4 - Identity Model Grant Types

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to implement Identity Model from [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2) , im trying to get the NetCoreConsoleClient working with my IdentityServer4 on my localhost:5000 and my Api also on my localhost:5001

My starting point is [Quick start 5](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html) Hybrid and Api flow.

So Ive added the following Client to my IdentityServer4 code:

```
// Hybrid grant client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "hclient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
            }
```

In the NetCoreConsoleClient I have changes the following lines of code:

```
    static string _authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    static string _api = "http://localhost:5001";

private static async Task SignIn()
    {
        // create a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
        string redirectUri = string.Format("http://127.0.0.1:7890/");

        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = _authority,
            ClientId = "hclient",
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = "OpenId Profile api1",
            FilterClaims = false,
            Browser = new SystemBrowser(port: 7890)
        };
```

I read in a posts comments [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/06/01/identitymodel-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-client-library-for-mobilenative-applications/) that I should use Hybrid flow grant type.

The web browser opens but I keep getting:

**Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the logs....

Comment: Logs will help but I can see you are not supplying the client secret to the OidcClientOptions object.

Comment: Did you get any results?